# How to prove family of rectangles to be semiring?

Tags: abstract-algebra, elementary-set-theory, semiring

Prove that $I_2 = \{[a,b) \times [c,d) \mid a,b,c,d\in\Bbb{R}\}$ is a semiring over $\Bbb{R}^2$.

Comment: A "semi-ring" is a set of objects with a binary operation defined on those objects.  Here I can see that you r objects are points in R2 but what operation are you assuming?

Comment: The objects appear to be subsets of $\mathbb{R}^2$. I know what a semiring is, but what is a semiring *over $\mathbb{R}^2$*?

Answer (score 1):

Let $A = \{[a_1,b_1) \times [c_1,d_1) \mid a_1,b_1,c_1,d_1\in\Bbb{R}\}$ and $B = \{[a_2,b_2) \times [c_2,d_2) \mid a_2,b_2,c_2,d_2\in\Bbb{R}\}$. Then 
$$
A\cap B=\begin{cases}(\max(a_1,a_2), \min(b_1, b_2))\times (\max(c_1,c_2), \min(d_1, d_2)), 
\\ \quad\quad\quad\max(a_1,a_2)\leqslant\min(b_1, b_2) \text{ and } \max(c_1,c_2)\leqslant\min(d_1, d_2)
\\ 
\varnothing, \quad\text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
$$
So clearly $A\cap B$ is a rectangle. Also $A\cup B$ is the union of at most $5$ rectangles.

Thus $I_2$ is semiring.